# Is a small amount of play on the Fujifilm X-E1 mount normal?

Tags: zoom, lens-mount, fujifilm

I have a brand new Fuji X-E1 with the 18-55 zoom. The lens has the barest amount of play once mounted, rotating back and forth less than a half millimeter if I twist it firmly. I've had old Nikon film SLR/lens combinations that did this - is it common with Fuji X-mount, or do I need to return the camera for warranty repair?

It's otherwise functional. The lens is locked to the body securely, and it takes fantastic photos (tho the zoom ring is a bit stiff. I may just not be used to it.)

Comment: Mine did not have this issue but given a sample of exactly one, I cannot tell you that it is common. Why don't you just go to a store and check yourself?

Comment: It's often hard to find Fujifilm in brick and mortar stores.

Comment: My X-1 has gone back to Fuji, there was so much play even moving the appature ring made the screen go off and I got a message saying "lens fault" It was the same with all 3 of the lenses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How loose can the lens mount be?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34144/how-loose-can-the-lens-mount-be)

Answer (score 3):

An *issue* you encounter is a normal thing - happens in nearly every bayonet. There are several reasons for that, most notably: manufacturing tolerances.

You can see this question for related answers: [How loose can the lens mount be?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/34144/15918)